# pass variable by jquery mobile from page to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have this code that fill ListView by xml file.

when i press on one item in the ListView i go to page2.

**how to pass the Fname, Lname , Phone ..... variables for the person that i pick in the ListView to page2 ?**

```
<script>
        var ALL;
        var ID, Fname, Lname, Phone, Car;

        function XX() {

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "DD.xml", false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

            $("#ZIBI").empty();

            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("men");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

                try{ID = x[i].getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                catch (err) { ID = "0";}
                try{Fname = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Fname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                catch (err) { Fname = "0"; }
                try{Lname = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Lname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                catch (err) { Lname = "0"; }
                try{Phone = x[i].getElementsByTagName("S_phone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                catch (err) { Phone = "0"; }
                try { Car = x[i].getElementsByTagName("car")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; }
                catch (err) { Car = "0"; }

                ALL = 
                      '<li>' +
                      '<a href="page2.html" data-transition="slidedown">' +
                      //'<a href="tel:' + Phone + '  data-icon="location">' +
                      '<img src="PIC/' + ID + '.jpeg">' +
                      '<p class="nam">' + Fname + " " + Lname + '</p>' +
                      '<p class="phn">' + Phone + '</p>' +
                      '<p class="crr">' + Car + '</p>' +
                      '</a>' +
                      '<a href="tel:' + Phone + '  data-icon="location" ></a>' +
                      '</li>' 

                $("#ZIBI").append(ALL);
                $("#ZIBI").listview("refresh");
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: What is the actual question: a) How to monitor the click and retrieve the correct values or b) how to pass it to the 2nd page? (for b) see below).

Answer (score 1):

In the new page you can use the following:

```
var fullname = $(this).find('p.nam').text();
var phone    = $(this).find('p.phn').text();
var car      = $(this).find('p.crr').text();
```

within the `click` handler for the link clicked.

**However,** if you have turned off ajax navigation, the above would not work.

```
$(document).on('click', 'li a', function() {
    //catch them here
});
```

Comment: thanks !! how to get those variables on page2 ? i have on page2 this: <h1 id="zNAME"> AA </h1> how to fill it with fullname ?

Comment: If you're positive `h1` has a unique `id`, then once you get the define the variables in the click handler, you can use them like so: `$('#zNAME').text( fullname );`

Comment: i try this on page index.html on -  $(document).on('click', 'li a', function () {zfullname = $(this).find('p.nam').text();  $("#zNAME").text(zfullname);}  but it wdont work

Comment: It should work once page2.html is loaded. I notice that you're using plain valina JS, mostly. Take a look at the jQuery Mobile API documentation. There are several events you can target. And remember, once page1.html loads, your index page will still be in the DOM so you can access it's elements.

Comment: i try this on page2 onload="PP();"  and function PP() contain  $("#zNAME").text(zfullname);  -  but still dont work.  i try also to put button on page2 that call PP() and this works. how to do it when the page2 is load ?